# Is there a contextually standard value for NaN for int?

Tags: int

1. In a lot of runtimes, the int type has a default value initialized.
2. Most languages do not by default provide a null holder for basic types.
3. A holder reference would cause an additional usually unnecessary member lookup.

Considering this, has a value emerged among programmers to specify null/uninitialized in acceptable contexts?

Presumably, a value just inside the range of the int type would be appropriate.

Comment: Well, NaN is a concept (IEEE 754?) for some invalid _floating point_ number. The trouble is, for integers, any combination of bits is an acceptable and valid number. The best you can do is declare some particular bit pattern (e.g., x7fffffff) to be reserved for some pseudo-NaN usage. Be careful about different sizes (number of bits) in use.

Comment: Just curious if there is an agreed upon pseudo-NaN

Comment: For _integers_? Not that I know of. It will just have to be something that will never legitimately occur in your application. For example, a count could be 0, 1, 2,..., so flags such as NaN could be -1, -2, etc. Just don't make the old Y2k mistake of YEAR=99 means "delete" file, etc.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples I can think of that are sometimes used:

- For an unsigned value, using a signed type and returning -1 to indicate error.
- MAX_INT or equivalent.